# bottom tab navigation gives a different result than in the doc

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

According to this [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/)
with the [example](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Material%20Bottom%20Tabs%20Navigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fmaterial-bottom-tab-example.js)

that gives this result :

[image: bottom nav]

why do I have always this result, with exactly the same code:

[image]

And the highlight on the tap doesn't work as well.
I checked all the dependencies and everything, it doesn't change.

Tips: I have the same result as this [doc](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/bottom-navigation.html) shows, why is that different ?

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Code in doc and code in example is not same

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some changes for same design. Enable `shifting` and `labeled`. Add `tabBarColor` in each `Tab.screen`.

```
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Feed"
      activeColor="white"
      labelStyle={{ fontSize: 12 }}
      shifting={true}
      labeled={true}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Feed"
        component={Feed}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarColor: 'red',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
           tabBarColor: 'blue',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarColor: 'green',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed all version, to previous and its working fine now:

```
react-native init datingapp --version 0.68.1

npm install @react-navigation/native@6.0.10
npm install react-native-screens@3.13.1
npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.3.1
npm install react-native-paper@4.12.1
npm install react-native-vector-icons@9.1.0
npm install @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs@6.2.1
npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
npm install jotai
npm install @react-navigation/native-stack@6.6.2
npm install react-native-gesture-handler@2.6.1
npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.3.1
npm install react-native-screens
```

[image]